# How can I delegate calls to a method to another method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to create another name for a method that already exists, e.g. I want to call `slice` with `only`. I don't want to change anything about the behavior of that original method, so it's not a redefinition, but delegation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do that in Ruby. Please check this post which may help you find your most suitable way of doing it.

http://gdakram.com/past/2010/12/2/multiple_ways_in_implementing_delegation_pattern_in_ruby/

Answer (score 1):

```
class Whatever
  def slice
    # do something
  end
  alias :only :slice
end
```